# fishで環境変数がうまく通らない

Tags: ubuntu, shell, deno, fish

fishでdenoのパスを通そうとしたんですが、うまく通りません。

```shell
set -x DENO_INSTALL /root/.deno
fish_add_path $DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH

# others...
```

`$ deno --version #=> Command "deno" not found, did you mean...(以下略)`

`export DENO_INSTALL=...`を叩いた場合、そのセッションだけでしか変数が保持されません。

### ubuntu root dir

```
.
├── .bash_history
├── .bash_profile
├── .bashrc
├── .bundle
├── .cache
├── .config
├── .dbus
├── .deno
├── .gitconfig
├── .irb_history
├── .local
├── .motd_shown
├── .npm
├── .profile
├── .pyenv
├── .rbenv
├── .redhat
├── .solargraph
├── .ssh
├── .viminfo
├── .vscode-server
├── .wget-hsts
└── fonts

14 directories, 9 files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fish_add_path $DENO_INSTALL/binと書き直すと通りました。